# TCP Throughput versus Packet Loss

Tags: tcp, throughput, packet-loss

How does the packet loss rate affect the TCP throughput rate: throughput rate reduce exponentially with respect to loss increase or throughput rate reduces by the same amount as loss increase?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer you are looking for, is that the exponential is the worst case, and the linear the best. In general when one or more packets are lost/damaged, they are resent, leading to a drop in throughput equal to the size of the packet payload/resend time. that said, if the resend itself fails and the packet must be resent again, the trend can approach exponential.

Keep in mind, there is only a general correlation between packets and volume of data, so a relationship between packet count and data volume only works for perfectly spherical chickens in a vaccuum (eg: only under artificial circumstances like a lab).

Answer (score 0):

I simulated this once, with random packet drops. One the simulated error rate exceeded about 2% there was a definite upwards curve (latency vs error rate), and beyond about 9% throughput basically ceased altogether. I wouldn't care to speculate what law the curve was.